# Is the %hint annotation imported/Dec and auto annotation?

Tags: annotations, idris, dependent-type

I have a datatype that depends on a predicate P : a -> Type, meaning that some of its data constructors refer have an implicit P x as argument. I would like idris to be able to automatically infer this implicit. For this, I annotated the implicit with the keyword auto and I wrote a function isP : (x : a) -> Dec (P x) with a %hint annotation before the type declaration. Namely, something like:

```
module P

P : a -> Type

%hint
isP : (x : a) -> Dec (P x)
```

and in a separate file

```
module Main

import P

data Foo : Type where
  Bar : (x : a) -> .{auto prf : P x} -> Foo
```

That said, I can't declare values of said Foo type because Idris claims the it can't infer prf.

Is this because prf has type P x instead of Dec (P x) or is it because the %hint flag does not get imported?

In either case, how can I get Idris to use a Dec value to try to find an implicit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%hint` flag is imported, as you guess, it's because `Dec (P x)` is different than `P x`.

There's a trick though, you can use this datatype:

```
data IsYes : prop -> Type where
  SoTrue : IsYes (Yes prop)
```

(basically, you define a type that holds a `Yes` for a given property)
and then you can use `default` instead of `auto` to check if the property holds:

```
data Foo : Type where
  Bar : (x : a) -> .{default SoTrue prf : IsYes (isP x)} -> Foo
```

Note: with this trick, you don't even need `%hint` anymore, you just check the outcome of `isP` at compile time.

Comment: Yes, it builds a Foo, my bad for the typo. Edited.

Comment: When I try this solution I get a type error when trying to define a Bar that is akin to: Type mismatch between IsYes (Yes prop) (Type of SoTrue) and IsYes (isP x) (Expected Type). My function isP is checked as total by Idris.

Comment: It should mean that `isP x` can't be evaluated to Yes. Can you check if it compiles if you define `isP` as `isP = Yes ?placeholder_1`?

Comment: No, replacing the body of isP with Yes ?h still yields the same error.

Comment: Solved the problem by making isP a public export instead of simply export

Comment: Oh right, I always forget about it: `public export` is often required at type level, as you have to inspect the definition to reduce the term